# resolveFully doesn't resolve nested references or normal references for Callbacks related PathItem

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

**Configurations** ==>

- OpenAPI version : 3.0.0
- Swagger-parser 2.0.26

**Issue** ==>
I am using the `resolveFully` parse option as mentioned [in the documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser#2-resolvefully) but seems its not working for most of my usecases *which involve callbacks and path item for callbacks*.

```
ParseOptions parseOptions = new ParseOptions();
parseOptions.setResolve(true);
parseOptions.setResolveFully(true);
OpenAPI result = new OpenAPIV3Parser().read("Swagger.json", null, parseOptions);
```

**My use-cases for Callbacks related PathItem are like below** ==>

1. Resolving nested schemas that might be referenced from "#components/schemas/"
2. Resolving requestBody referenced from "#components/requestBodies/"
3. Resolving response referenced from "#components/responses/"
4. Resolving callback referenced from "#components/callbacks/"
5. Combination of point 2,1
6. Combination of point 3,1
7. Combination of point 4,3,21

Looks like an issue. Technically it should resolve the local references and place it as the inline definitions in the OpenAPI document java object, if I am not mistaken reading the mentioned [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser#2-resolvefully).

Comment: You may try using openapi4j instead of swagger-parser.

Comment: Hi @erosb , the parser is not resolving the $ref by placing it inline. Anything specific to be done. I have referred https://www.openapi4j.org/parser.html

Comment: When you say not working, what is not working? Are you getting an error? Can you upload your `swagger.json` file.

Comment: Hi @BossMan actually it'll just not resolve the Callback related PathItem. There are no errors or exceptions as such thrown. Just that the `resolveFully` `ParseOption` was supposed to resolve but which it was failing for the aforementioned scenarios. But I have provided the answer to this, please have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the Callbacks PathItem related members were not getting resolved using the resolveFully ParseOptions that we set as shown in code snippet.

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/pull/1589) PR for the same [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/1579) raised by me on the SwaggerParser project and now its closed as the PR was merged to master.

Hopefully, it should be a part of the 2.0.28 release.